# Why I can not scrape a table from a dynamic web page

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, scrape

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://ntr.tourism.government.bg/CategoryzationAll.nsf/mn.xsp"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')

print(soup)



data = []
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'table table-striped table-hover mnastaniavane dataTable no-footer'})
table_body = table.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
```

Here is the web page: https://ntr.tourism.government.bg/CategoryzationAll.nsf/mn.xsp I'd like to scrape all hotels for an university project in a specific location (for example Varna - the location is in Cyrilic). I find the source code and describe the exact table - but I can't scrape any row/element etc form it.
Any recommendation please!?
Although there is a lot of information at the moment I do not find a useful code to scrape the table

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium (python library) to scrape data from web pages that generate data dynamically, you can download chrome drive from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/to/chromedriver", options=options)

url = "https://ntr.tourism.government.bg/CategoryzationAll.nsf/mn.xsp"
driver.get(url)

table_confirm = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
  ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "mnastaniavane"))
)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'lxml')

print(soup)



data = []
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'table table-striped table-hover mnastaniavane dataTable no-footer'})
table_body = table.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed I am sure it will help me a lot - I will install chrome driver later cause I need more time & try your method as well - then prbably I'll be able to scrape any page pointed  from the dropdown menu with the chosen criteria! 
Thank  u very much again!

Answer (score 0):

Data are coming from Ajax request so you can just do the ajax request, don't have to render the page, this is much faster.

For example this is the first 4 columns of the 20 rows of the page:

```py
import requests

url = "https://ntr.tourism.government.bg/CategoryzationAll.nsf/api/data/collections/name/vRegistarMNValid?sortcolumn=CNumber&sortorder=ascending&ps=20&page=0&_=1624898715559"
rows = requests.get(url).json() # list of the 20 rows, rows are dict.

# Uncomment to see all the columns title.
# print(rows[0].keys())

for row in rows:
    print(row["CNumber"], row["TOSubType1"], row["TOName"], row["TOCity"])
```

Output:

```sh
0000000012 Семеен хотел Семеен хотел "ХЕЛГА" Горна Митрополия
00001 Къща за гости "ЛИДИЯ" Батак
00001 Стаи за гости самостоятелни стаи к-с "Барите" Чернево
00001 Стаи за гости СТАИ ЗА ГОСТИ "ГОРХИМ" Рила
00001 Стаи за гости СТАИ ЗА ГОСТИ Брестовица
00001 Къща за гости Къща за гости - ловен и селски туризъм Хърсово
00001 Хотел Иглен Ъглен
00001 Къща за гости РЕЛАКС/RELAX/ Батак
00001 Къща за гости  Батак
00001 Къща за гости ВИЛИ-ПЕТЯ № 1 Батак
00001 Къща за гости "Форест Лодж" Банско
00001 Къща за гости "ОМД" ООД Земен
00001 Стаи за гости Дунавска перла Попина
00001 Къща за гости КЪЩА ЗА ГОСТИ "БЛАГОВЕСТА" Илинденци
00001 Стаи за гости Георгиевата къща Генерал Кантарджиево
00001 Къща за гости "Дунковата къща" Падала
000011 Къща за гости Гостилица Гостилица
00002 Стаи за гости Стаи за гости Загражден
00002 Апартаменти за гости апартамент за гости №15 в жилищна сграда ,Мърфис Лодж" Банско
00002 Къща за гости ВИЛИ-ПЕТЯ № 2 Батак
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response, Dorian! I can't believe. Could you please tell me how u manage to open this url with the API: https://ntr.tourism.government.bg/CategoryzationAll.nsf/api/data/collections/name/vRegistarMNValid?sortcolumn=CNumber&sortorder=ascending&ps=20&page=0&_=1624898715559
Then probably I will be able by myself to extract the information i need for a specific destination - from the dropdown menus (city, number of beds, etc.) with algorithm you provide, I'll add more columns only
Once again Respect for this lesson! |

Comment: You're welcome. In general for dynamic webpage data can be embeded in script tag, or coming from ajax request (XHR), or Websocket (WS) if there is bidirectionnal communication. So you can use your browser inspector to look at the network activity and find api url. Hope it helps.

Comment: I managed from the developer tools and selected the Network option from the drop-down menu at the top! 
The rest is to save it in a data frame and export as csv! 
Stay safe, Dorian!

Comment: Could you advise me which method shouls I use to save scraped data in a DataFrame?
I tried converting array in DataFrame but couldnt create a DataFrame ready to save in csv